# Sending message, XPCOM object, that cannot be cloned

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, xpcom

In this **WebExtension**, I'm trying to log all request urls in the **background script**, and send them in a message to the **content script**.

In the background script I add a listener:

```
browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  logURL,
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
);
```

This listener *used* to work (for many months), and then paf, in the last few weeks, I get this error in `MessageChannel.jsm:553:6`:

> Sending message that cannot be cloned. Are you trying to send an XPCOM object?

The function, `logURL` is never called. I suspect something has changed with **firefox**, and I'm behind the times. But then again, maybe intercepting the `onHeadersReceived` isn't the best way to log requests in the first place?

Is there a reason `onHeadersReceived.addListener` has stopped calling `logURL`?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in FF.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: While it does *sound* like a bug, it may not be. Please provide a complete [MCVE] (which would be needed to reproduce the bug anyway). You can also work on tracking down in which version of Firefox the change happened to make it go from working to not working. You should also look into if it's an issue with your version using multiprocess vs. single-process.